# Looking for question containing "&" and "&&"

Tags: support, search

I was looking for questions containing `&` and `&&` so I typed this in the search bar :

```
& and && operator
```

and SO throw me this:

> > results found containing
> >
> > **and operator**

I tried to escape it, use the ASCII char but I didn't find anything. How can I search it ?

Comment: See also [How to search for special characters on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38968) (Symbolhound can scan SO for specific syntax constructs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may enclose the search string in double quotes `"`, which will give you this search url for `&&`:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q="%26%26"
```

to filter it further for questions, add `is:q` to the search criteria.