# What is the purpose of double quotes in search?

Tags: support, search

As an example, I wanted to search for `term_variables`. I currently got

- <s>25</s> 46 hits [without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=term_variables)
- <s>0</s> 4 hits with [double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22term_variables%22)

The advance search tips say:

> exact "words here".

([This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276103/looking-for-question-containing-and) did not help, it claims again that its about the exact characters)

Comment: To clarify, the search with and without quotes does not include spaces. It is the same term just with or without quotes. And it sees different results?

Comment: @NHDaly: Yes different results with and without, try above queries!

Comment: Quotes are supposed to mean "search for the exact phrase."  If that's not what they mean, it's a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if that is its purpose but the difference is that with quotes

> "term_variables"

you'll get only search results where that exact phrase is present in the post but **NOT** in a code `<code>` block. You might get confused by [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34671164/578411) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32651292/578411) because they use a `<pre>` html tag to mimic a code layout.

If you search for a single word without quotes

> term_variables

you'll get results where the phrase is used in either text or code.